# Use find command to find files for certain day

Tags: shell, unix

In unix shell I use find command to find files if i need files for last certain days I use following command:  `find . -type f -name "<filename>" -print`

Now if I want files for last 10 days I use :

`find . -type f -name "<filename>" -mtime -10 -print`

Now suppose I want to find all files with file name and suppose a date how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find files modified on certain day (let's say 30th Apr 2014):

```
find . -type f -newermt 2014-04-30 ! -newermt 2014-05-01
```

Comment: Manual entry for newerat not found or not installed.
so I have to use some other command